# Why this action results an empty file on client side?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, streamwriter, memorystream, fileresult

Why this action results an empty file on client side ??

```
public FileResult download()
{

    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

    FileStreamResult fs = new FileStreamResult(stream, "text/plain");
    fs.FileDownloadName = "file.txt";

    writer.WriteLine("this text is missing !!! :( ");

    writer.Flush();
    stream.Flush();

    return fs;                  
}
```

Comment: I think the code is self-explanatory.

Comment: Maybe because you flush strem before return it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be because the underlying stream (in your case a MemoryStream) is not positioned at the beginning when you return it to the client.

Try this just before the return statement:

```
stream.Position = 0
```

Also, these lines of code:

```
writer.Flush();
stream.Flush();
```

Are not required because the stream is Memory based. You only need those for disk or network streams where there could be bytes that still require writing.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```